# How to use $window.open to display html page instead of downloading it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to display an HTML page by using:

```
$window.open('https://xxx.html', '_blank');
```

However it keeps downloading the html file instead of displaying it.

What should I do in order to display the HTML page in a new tab?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you load that path directly in browser address bar?

Comment: @charlietfl: It's also downloading the html page

Comment: Then it is a server side configuration problem

Comment: @charlietfl: Great thanks ! :-)